# Error while configuring AWS IOT with WSO2 DAS

Tags: java, wso2, mqtt, aws-iot, wso2-das

I tried to configure WSO2 DAS mqtt receiver with the AWS IOT server as mention below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eventReceiver name="mqttIot" statistics="disable" trace="disable" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventreceiver">
<from eventAdapterType="mqtt">
    <property name="topic">/device-data</property>
    <property name="cleanSession">true</property>
    <property name="url">tcp://<url>:8883</property>
</from>
<mapping customMapping="disable" type="text"/>
<to streamName="sonsor.in.event.data.stream" version="1.0.0"/>
</eventReceiver>
```

Also tried with changing port 8883 and 443. but getting same error.

```
 ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.mqtt.internal.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
 Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:100)
    ... 1 more
```

This is working fine with the inbound endpoint on WSO2 ESB. do i need any other additional configuration on DAS side ?

Comment: How many clients do you use to connect to this endpoint?

Comment: Just only one client.